# Xubuntu 14.04: How do I know if I'm using my NVidia 740M when playing games?

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, gpu

I currently installed Wine and I'm successfully playing Diablo III. However, when I check my FPS, it's around 40 FPS. My computer is an ASUS X550LB with 8GB of RAM and an NVidia GeForce 740M. I believe the specs are alright and should run a game like Diablo III at around 50 - 60 FPS. How do I check if my NVIDIA video card is activated?

EDIT: Whenever I run

> lspci | egrep '3D|VGA'

this shows up:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
>
> 04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev ff)

Is there anything wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
nvidia-settings
```

It would open Nvidia X Server Settings and show you if you are over Intel (Power Saving) or Nvidia (Performance)

You can also use that command to switch between modes.

Comment: I opened nvidia-settings and only saw "Application Profiles" and nvidia-settings-configuration. What do I do next?

Comment: You must have nvidia-prime installed.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics

Comment: I had nvidia-prime installed however my games aren't loading. I think I'm supposed to use the X.org driver instead of the nvidia driver.